# $\sin(x)\cos(\pi/x)$ is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is this function defined on $(0,\infty)$ uniformly continuous? 
$$\sin(x)\cos(\pi/x)$$

Efforts:

I know $\cos(\pi/x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the domain. Can I use this to solve the problem?

Any hints?

Comment: **Hint.** Start by extending to $x=0$ by continuity,

Comment: @Henning  At x=0 we define function to be 0. Now it is uniform continuous on $[0, n]$. And if we can increase $n$ as much we want. If we take union of such sets. We get the desired result. I am not sure with my argument.

Comment: x @Tensor_Product: That's an excellent start but things break down when you take the infinite unions of $[0,n]$. If that were valid you would be able to prove that _every_ continuous function is uniformly continuous, which is not true. But perhaps combine this with the fact that your function is Lipschitz on $[k,\infty)$?

Comment: @Henning since the derrivative is bounded on say $[1, \infty)$, function is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$. And combine with the fact that function is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. We can comclude that function is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]\cup[1,\infty)=[0, \infty)$.

Comment: x @Tensor: Yes, _that_ looks convincing.

Answer (score 1):

This function is uniformly continuous. Note that $|f(x)| \leq |\sin x| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $|f(x)-\sin x| \leq |1-\cos \frac {\pi} x| \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$
. Combined with the facts that $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous and any continuous function is uniformly continuous on $[-N,N]$ for each $N$ you can show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I am reading from K A Ross book. Which idea you have used here?

Comment: It is uniformly continuous as my proof shows. You just have to repeatedly use triangle inequality to complete the proof

Comment: @Tensor_Product I don't have Ross' book. I am using two facts: 1) $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ (This follows easily from Mean Value Theorem) 2) Any continuous function on a compact interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous. This is a standard theorem.